# SQL Report Writer Datepart function

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am trying to use the datepart function in SQL Report Writer 3.0 to extract the month from the current date.

I am doing it like this `=DatePart("m", Today())`

This is returning - 36775

I am trying to get it to return - 5

Am I missing something here?

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Try an uppercase `M`.

Comment: I've tried that. It returns the same 36775. Thanks

Comment: How about `=DatePart(DateInterval.Month, Today())`?

Comment: Tried that also and it returns 36775 as well.

Comment: That's odd.  I wonder if there's something else going on?  Perhaps a strange format on the TextBox?  Does `=42` return 36775?  (Trying to remove `DatePart()` from the equation)

Comment: `=DatePart("m", Today())` returns *5* for me when displayed in a Textbox. Seems like there's something else going on here. Maybe you should try the expression in a new report and see if that's any different? As per @DanPichelman, I agree it seems like something else rather than the expression itself.

Comment: You guys are right. The text box was doing a sum(). I was totally on the wrong path. It's working now. Thanks for the help!